# How to tell which columns have been set to CASCADE in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cascade

I'm curious to know if there's away to tell which columns have been set to CASCADE using mysql.  Doing DESC TABLE; doesn't appear to produce anything obvious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.1.10, you can obtain this information from the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-schema.html) by joining [`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/referential-constraints-table.html) to [`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/key-column-usage-table.html):

```sql
SELECT kcu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
 USING (CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME)
WHERE  'CASCADE' IN (rc.DELETE_RULE, rc.UPDATE_RULE)
   AND kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

Comment: +1 For goodness sake eggyal, stop showing me up by finding better and cleverer ways :P

Comment: Actually, it is brilliant, I learn better ways of doing things from you, so keep up the great work sir!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the:

```
show create table tableName;
```

which will output a create table that has the references to cascading deletes.

Example snagged from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE ibtest11c\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: ibtest11c
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `ibtest11c` (
  `A` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `D` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `B` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `C` varchar(175) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`A`,`D`,`B`),
  KEY `B` (`B`,`C`),
  KEY `C` (`C`),
  CONSTRAINT `0_38775` FOREIGN KEY (`A`, `D`)
REFERENCES `ibtest11a` (`A`, `D`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,    // <--- This is what you are looking for
  CONSTRAINT `0_38776` FOREIGN KEY (`B`, `C`)
REFERENCES `ibtest11a` (`B`, `C`)       // <--- This is what you are looking for
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```